# Time trigger not calling function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my Google sheet there a function called onOpen which will check Column C, If the value in Column C is **Closed**, then that row should move to next sheet.

This function is working fine, when I'm editing sheet directly. The problem is function will not work If I update sheet with AppSheet, Also, Time trigger will not run in Google sheet.

```js
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();


  if (s.getName() == "Load Board" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == "Closed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

}
```

Comment: I believe that is because the `onOpen` event will only occur when you open the sheet in Google Sheets. Maybe look at creating a trigger that will fire when an edit is made to the spreadsheet instead? Also, you mention your time trigger function, but it doesn't look like you posted your time trigger function

Comment: @Adjit I tried onEdit, this will run. But it will  only run when I edit sheet directly,NOT when I edit sheet with third party like AppSheet

Comment: And your time driven trigger doesn't work? Because I know you can set it to fire every hour/every minute

Comment: There is also an `onChange` trigger, which I have not used, but have you tried that as well?

Comment: @Adjit Right now Im using onChange, same thing It will work if I make changes directly, not with time,

Comment: @Adjit Looks like other trigger like onEdit is working it's just Time Trigger is not running

Comment: Yeah, if it were me, I wouldn't necessarily trust google's time triggers. I mostly use this with forms and spreadsheets to send a confirmation email when the form has been submitted. But that had given me problems a while back with randomly choosing when to fire, so it was missing form submissions. However, Google seems to have fixed that issue since it has been working as expected now. I would try and set up a few functions to send you an email at certain time's. This way you have lets say 3 different times for your time trigger to activate, and you can see if it really is not firing at all

Comment: @Adjit But in my case time trigger is not running at ALL. My concern is Am I applying Trigger correctly?

Comment: You may just be setting it up wrong. Just put together a time trigger that works well. I'll post my test

Comment: Working on this now, a bit backed up at work. Just bear with me

Comment: Did any of this help?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell how exactly you are setting up your events to fire.

Here is how I would set up a simple test to make sure that everything is working as you expected.

First, in your script attached to your spreadsheet set up your test function:

```
function timeDrivenTestFunction() {
  var emailName = "Time Driven Admin";
  var replyTo = "no-reply@someDomain.com";
  var email = "yourEmail@someDomain.com";
  var body = "Timestamp: " + Date.now();
  var subject = "Timestamp Test";

  var advancedArgs = {
    name: emailName,
    replyTo: replyTo,
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: body,
    noReply: true
  };

  var autoReplyErr = "Error in sending email message. No reply was sent";

  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail(advancedArgs);
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(errorEmail, autoReplyErr);
  }      
}
```

Now that you have that set up you can add triggers to your project.

**Step 1** - Go to `Current project's triggers`

[image: Go To Current Project's Triggers]

**Step 2** - Add a new trigger

[image: Add new trigger]

**Step 3** - Set your test function to run as a time driven event every minute. Then click on notifications to bring you to Step 4

[image: Set function to run and notifications]

**Step 4** - Set up error notifications, so that if the function fails to execute it will send your gmail an email message telling you that the function failed to execute and will also state the reason why it didn't execute (ie. it will give you some sort of error message)

[image]

**Step 5** - Click OK, and Save then wait a few minutes for it to kick in. It should work well, you may just need to set up permissions in your spreadsheet in order to allow Google Docs to access your gmail and send emails.